# gnuplot - adding median to plot with errorbars AND logscale'd x-axis

Tags: gnuplot, median, errorbar

So I have some data files in format

```
x y ymin ymax
```

That I'm plotting with yerrorbars.

Now how would I best add a median of the `y` values to the plot running over the whole range of `x`?

**UPDATE**

I'm also plotting the x axis in `logscale` which seems to prevent using `STATS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that your data looks like this:

```
1 8 6 9
2 6 5 7
3 5 4 8
4 6 5 8
```

We can use the `stats` command to find the median.  The use is similar to the plot command.  Here, we only need to do analysis of the second column, so we will only specify the second column:

```
stats datafile u 2 nooutput
```

The *nooutput* option tells the command not to print the results.  If we wish to see the full analysis, we simply omit that specification.  By default, the `stats` command stores its results in variables of the form **STATS_***.  We can use a different prefix if desired.  See `help stats` for more details.

At this point, we have a variable **STATS_median** that stores the median of the y values (which is 6 for the sample data).  We can now add the median to the graph in one of two ways.  First we can simply add a plot specification to the existing plot command:

```
plot datafile u 1:2:3:4 with yerrorbars, STATS_median
```

[image]

or we can add a line with the `set arrow` command and then plot just the yerrorbars:

```
set arrow 1 from graph 0, first STATS_median to graph 1, first STATS_median nohead
plot datafile u 1:2:3:4 with yerrorbars
```

[image]

Here we give the x coordinate in graph units which range from 0 (the left side) to 1 (the right side) and the y coordinate in the *first* coordinate system which corresponds to the y1 axis.  Specifying `nohead` says to not draw an arrow head.  The 1 immediately following `set arrow` tags this arrow as arrow 1 so that we can change or remove it easily later.

Other options are available.  See `help arrow` for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much. However, there's a small problem ... I'm plotting the x axis in ``logscale`` and gnuplot is refusing to let me use STATS when I do. I don't suppose you have a solution to that as well?

Comment: @User1291 It seems to work just fine if you run the stats command BEFORE you issue `set logscale x`.  Everything else works with the logscale turned on.

Comment: No, it doesn't... keeps telling me "Stats command not available with logscale active".

Comment: Correction, it actually does work. My error was that I had started gnuplot and then loaded the script, which resulted in the logscale's still being active from earlier attempts. Re-opening gnuplot did the trick.

Comment: there is a command to set x back to linear: `unset logscale x` (for each `set` ther's an `unset`). Another good thing is to put a `reset` on top of your script `script.gp`, so that it by calling `load 'script.gp'` you will always have a clean gnuplot